# Error while finding the running sum of an array in C++ using vectors

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, vector

Why am i getting this error, while finding the running sum of an array in c++?

```
Line 1034: Char 34: runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x6020000000b0 overflowed to 0x6020000000ac (stl_vector.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:34".
```

the code is:

```cpp
    class Solution {
    public:
        vector<int> runningSum(vector<int>& nums) {
          vector<int> temp(nums.size());
            nums[0]=temp[0];
            for(int i=0;i<nums.size();i++){
                temp[i]=temp[i-1]+nums[i];
            }
              return temp;
        }
    };
```

Comment: When `i` is zero, then `i-1` indexes the vector out of bounds. Even the address sanitizer caught this issue precisely, telling you that you overflowed to a lower address. Consider using [std::partial_sum](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sum) instead of rolling your own potentially less efficient and more bug-prone version.

Comment: Please do not use leetcode to teach yourself C++. It will help you with your problem solving skills, but the kind of C++ code shown there is of very dubious quality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nums[0]=temp[0]` is incorrect, since `temp[0]` is 0 currently. It should be the other way around.

Also, the lower bound for the `for` loop should be `i=1`.

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> runningSum(vector<int>& nums) {
      vector<int> temp(nums.size());
        temp[0] = nums[0];
        for(int i=1;i<nums.size();i++){
            temp[i]=temp[i-1]+nums[i];
        }
          return temp;
    }
};
```